# What are the main differences between using DRb and TCPSocket for distributed Ruby programs?

Tags: ruby, tcpsocket, drb

If I wanted to create a multi-process client-server type of system where a Ruby program is the client and another Ruby program is the server, what are the important factors when deciding whether to implement this with DRb vs TCPSocket? Both seem to allow two-way communication between the two processes.

Are there any areas where one approach is better than the other? For example, if you need multiple clients to be able to concurrently access the server process.

Comment: Do you ever see yourself replacing one or the other peer with a program in another language?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. Right now, I don't see an essential difference between DRb and TCPSocket except that that latter may involve a little more setup.